# Compact splitting and new line manipulation in java with ArrayLists and HashMaps

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap

I am still in the process of developing this code and I am looking ideas to do this in a efficient and compact ways as I intend to embed this in a separate java code. I am open to ideas for other methods too although I wold prefer HashMap or ArrayList methods

I have a file  that I  am working with that looks like this:

```
053 100% BRAN       A0 B1 C01 E0
054 100% NATURAL    A0 B1 C01 E0 F0 G0
```

the end product of this code has to look like

```
053 016% BRAN       A0 
053 100% BRAN       B1 
053 100% BRAN       C01 
053 100% BRAN       E0 
054 100% NATURAL    A0
054 100% NATURAL    B1 
054 100% NATURAL    C01 
054 100% NATURAL    E0 
054 100% NATURAL    F0 
054 100% NATURAL    G0
```

Please note that the file is very large. All columns are tab separated and the last column as space separated elements.

EDIT: I am sorry I should have framed my question better.I was thinking of collections because after doing this I need to be able to access all the lines with different keys (the repeating values of the first column).

Comment: Why do you need to do anything with `HashMap` or `ArrayList`? Just split the input and print the lines.

Comment: I assume the `016%` is a mistake. You should be able to do this with string manipulation and you don't need a collection.

Answer (score 1):

If the pattern is fixed, then this can be done using RegEx. The `get();` will take each line as input and returns the list of all combinations for that input string

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String input="053 100% BRAN       A0 B1 C01 E0";            

    System.out.println(get(input));     

}

public static List<String> get(String input){

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    String regEx="((?:\\d*)\\s(?:\\d*)%\\s(?:[A-Z]*))([\\s]*)([\\sA-Z0-9]*)";
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regEx).matcher(input);            

    String firstHalf="";
    String codes="";
    if(matcher.matches()) { 
        firstHalf=matcher.group(1)+matcher.group(2);
        codes=matcher.group(3);
    }

    for (String code : codes.split("\\s")) {
        list.add(firstHalf+code);           
    }


    return list;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear why you need a collection at all. Just manipulate the strings:

```
for (String line : input) {
  String prefix = line.substring(0, 20);  // Or however you decide on the line prefix.
  String suffix = line.substring(20);

  for (String part : suffix.split(" ")) {
    System.out.printf("%s%s%n", prefix, part);
  }
}
```

You can do it more efficiently than this, by using a `PrintWriter` to avoid explicitly constructing the substrings/split array.

Comment: From what OP said at the end "All columns are tab separated" so that structure in posted example may be just for nice presentation, but not form of raw data. This means using `substring` may not be safe choice.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Test {  

    public static void main (String[] args){
       List<String[]> myList = new ArrayList<>();
       //read each line of your file and split it by \s+
       try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get("C:\\temp\\xyz.txt"))) {
            stream.forEach( line->{
                String[] splited = line.split("\\s+");
                //iterate from 4th element of your splited array to last
                //and add the first three elements and the ith element to your list
                for(int i = 3; i<splited.length; i++){
                    myList.add(new String [] {splited[0] ,splited[1], splited[2], splited[i]});                    
                }
            });
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        //print or do other stuff with your list
        myList.forEach(e->{System.out.println(Arrays.toString(e));});
    } 

}
```